# Android - how to make GridLayoutManager wrap RecycledView items

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I want the items in the RecycledView to be wrapped if there is enough space on the screen, much like how the Google Play Store is designed. How can I achieve this?

Recycled View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sensor_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensor_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sensor_image" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

OnCreateView():

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Dashboard, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.dashboard_recycler_view);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, 2);

        recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(20));

        return view;
    }
```

How it looks so far:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the items don't wrap, they just shrink so they can fit in the view.